# How protect page against High Tech CRSF

Tags: javascript, ajax, security, web-applications, http-headers

Technology range: PHP, MySQL, Apache, javascript, ajax.

**CRSF**

User is logged into his secure page.

Page uses a random token and random name. (For Input)

```
   <input name="random_name" value="random_token" />
```

Random_name and Random_token are stored in user SESSION.

Script checks header (HTTP 1.1 - referrer).

In my opinion these methods can't protected me vs Ajax (Page output) analysing.

---

**Ajax (Page output) analyse:**

User was visit a bad page.

After loaded page,
Ajax made a connection (with a prepared HTTP referrer header) to his page.
And download data.

Parse output (inputs).

And after successful parse.

Create own request with, Random_name, Random_token and prepared referrer header.

---

Security system accepted this action. (Referrer - OK, Token - OK)

How do I avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

When XMLHttpRequest was designed, this scenario was already token into account. The result was that XMLHttpRequest level 1 (historic) did not allow any cross-origin request at all. And with XMLHttpRequest level 2 (current), a client is only allowed to read the response to a cross-origin request if the server allows it according to the [Cross-Origin Request Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/).

So unless the request originates from the same origin or you allow any origin, a client is not allowed to read the response.

Comment: And yet that doesn't prevent someone from using the process he outlines with cURL and normal HTTP requests.

Comment: @RobertK That wouldn’t be CSRF.

Comment: True, it would require a combination of XSS & CSRF to work around even a simple token (via Ajax). Maybe he means that the user can issue custom commands/requests after the page loads and his token field/value are set?

Comment: For 60 - 90 minutes I'll show you a living example. (With comment in code)